# Fractions with setMinimumFractionDigits Java

Tags: java, fractions

I want to set the minimum number of fraction digits below

```
double a = 1d / 3;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(30);
System.out.println(nf.format(a));
```

But it gives result as

```
    0.333333333333333300000000000000
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: The precision of `double` is limited to approximately 16 decimal digits. It doesn't make a lot of sense to try to print 30 digits from a `double`. Use `BigDecimal` if you need unlimited precision floating-point numbers.

Comment: @Jesper.. I think you should post it as an answer, so that OP can accept it..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(1);
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(3);
    System.out.println(b1.divide(b2, 30, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP));
```

Answer (score 1):

The precision of the type `double` is limited to approximately 16 decimal digits (see: [Double-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). So, it doesn't make a lot of sense to print 30 digits from a `double`.

Use `BigDecimal` if you need unlimited precision floating-point numbers.